# Failed to bind to address - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions VS debugging .NET Core

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I regularly get this error when debugging an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API application in Kestrel on the `app.Run()` line within `Program.cs`.  The port in this case was 43399.

[image]

Here are some things that will sometimes resolve it:

- Closing the Visual Studio (2022) instance with the app in question
- Closing ALL Visual Studio instances
- Closing all active Windows within Visual Studio
- Rebooting

When I close all Visual Studio instances, I can at least count on the port not being occupied. However, when the problem does occur, the port is held by system, even though closing all Visual Studio instances will release it:

```
$processes = (Get-NetTCPConnection | ? {($_.State -eq "Listen") -and ($_.LocalPort -eq "44399")
}) | select OwningProcess, LocalPort
foreach ($process in $processes) {
    Get-Process -PID $process.OwningProcess | select ID,ProcessName, @{Name='LocalPort'; Expression={$process.LocalPort}}
}
```

The act of starting the debugger will both acquire and lock out the port at the same time.

[image]

If I start the process without debugging first, I can get it to start, and then I can run a debug session after that, but that might only work once before the port gets locked again and Visual Studio must be rebooted.

**What is causing this?**

Update:

I think it's worth posting my launchSettings.json after a suggestion from @Rena to change the port.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59999",
      "sslPort": 44398
    }
  },
  //profile can be selected with the start debug button in the toolbar
  "profiles": {
    "Proj.Web-Dev": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44398;http://localhost:59999",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "hotReloadEnabled": true
    },
    "Proj.Web-QA": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44398;http://localhost:59999",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "QA"
      },
      "hotReloadEnabled": true
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Switching the port does get me around the locked port.  However, when starting up the debugger, the old 44399 port still ends up being locked by system.

Comment: What if you alter the port number in the `applicationUrl` setting in the `launchSettings.json` file?

Comment: @Rena I will try that the next  time it does it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution / workaround for the problem was (also) to switch the port in the launchSettings.json.